# Cookies and REST

Tags: rest

Roy Fielding in his dissertation says:

> HTTP contradicts the desired properties of the generic interface with the introduction of
>   site-wide state information in the form of HTTP cookies.

Fielding also describes that REST's generic interface as composed of the following four constraints:

> 1. Identification of resources
> 2. Manipulation of resources through representations
> 3. Self-descriptive messages
> 4. Hypermedia as the engine of application state.

Which of the above constraints are violated by the use of cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the no. 4

```
Cookie interaction fails to match REST's model of application state, 
often resulting in confusion for the typical browser application.
```